# rectifying utf-8

Tags: php, utf-8

On my site a lot of users have foreign names and they are coming out funny for a chat script ive recently bought and i was wondering if there were any php functions or anything that could sort it out.

Please note how they are coming out funny, is how they are stored in the database.

Alicia CarreÃ±o
GeneviÃ¨ve

For example.

So how can I used php to make these look correct?

Thanks

EDIT: when using MYSQL, they seem to  come out correct, but not when pasted into the html itself or echoed out

EDIT 2:

I ran this in phpmyadmin: "mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p  --opt --quote-names \
    --skip-set-charset --default-character-set=latin1 general > general-dump.sql
"

The error was: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p --opt --quote-names \ --skip-set-charset' at line 1"

EDIT 3:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<?php       
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
$select = mysql_select_db('general',$connection);
$result = mysql_query('SELECT name FROM exchange WHERE `id`= 192');
$results = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $results['name'];


?>
```

Comment: One of these: -▷|- ? (In relation to your title) ;)

Comment: Hint: search for `SET NAMES utf8`. Database problems with UTF-8 have been posed a thousand times already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your *database connection* to UTF-8 to tell the database that data that will be sent to it will be in UTF-8 and data that comes back from it should be in UTF-8:

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connection);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php.

Comment: basically, in the database its stored wrong, but when i use the above code in edit 3 it displays fine, but then i applied what you said and it now went back to how it is in the database which is bad

Comment: That means your database connection is now working as it should, and you're seeing the data as it's stored in the database. The problem is that the data in your database is garbage, since you've been using it wrong before.

Comment: @Jake I've been sitting on this article for a while and decided to upload it just for you now: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 1):

There are at least half a dozen places where the encoding/charset can be wrong, and it's difficult to say which one is to blame. Quite often there are several. So I'd advise to start by reading [this article about Unicode](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). It's not the shortest, but it will be one of the most valuable 20 minutes of your programming career. After that, and some careful thinking, you should be able to identify the source and solution to your problems.

Comment: Admittedly I'm somewhat biased, but I'd recommend [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) over Joel's... :o)

Comment: @deceze - Interesting, I haven't read that one. I definitely will!

Comment: @deceze - OK, I read it. I think that both articles complement each other. Joel's article does a better job of explaining "what is what", while David's article focuses on the implications.

Answer (score 0):

They're most probably stored incorrectly in your database. Use Adminer, PHPMyAdmin or a query string to change the field, table or database (I recommend the latter) to `utf8_general_ci`. You probably have it at the default `latin`-something encoding, which doesn't support UTF8 characters.

---

The command you tried to run in PHPMyAdmin in your OP has to be run from the console; it's not an SQL query, hence the syntax error. Try using PHPMA's built-in export and import tabs to export and import your data.

Comment: ive changed it, are the values meant to change too? else what do i do with my 5,000 members?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to either export your data, change the database encoding, then reimport. You can do it with an `UPDATE` statement, which is documented at the bottom of [this](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Convert_latin1_to_UTF-8_in_MySQL) page.

Comment: so if i now insert Alicia CarreÃ±o GeneviÃ¨ve into the database, it would come out correct in the database or?

Comment: Inserting your mangled string would store as a mangled string, however if you use an `UPDATE` query or export/re-import your data, it should be encoded correctly.

Comment: i only have access to phpmyadmin and cant get the commands to work

Comment: shall i run it through mac terminal?

Comment: PHPMyAdmin should run it fine in the query editor. _How_ are the commands not working? Do you get errors? If so, please post them as an edit to your original question.

Comment: ok, so i exported it, changed to utf, imported again and its still the same

Comment: In that case, have a alook at Vilx- answer. As he says, it might not be in MySQL that this is happening.

Comment: well, in the database the value is clearly "MaÃªva" for example, and by using the php and html (see edit 3 on my OP) it comes out correct as "Maêva" - so how is it doing this?! The problem is, is that the script i got isnt doing it and its coming out as it is in the db